# Computing matrix norms without loop in numpy

Tags: python, numpy

How do I compute matrix norms within (100, 8, 8) matrix such that I have 100 norm-list vector at the end? E.g I want the norm of every 8x8 matrix.

Right now I do, but it is probably too inefficient and ugly

```
norms = []
for m in mats:
    norms.append(np.linalg.norm(m, ord='fro'))
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`numpy.linalg.norm`](https://numpy.org/devdocs/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.norm.html) accepts an `axis` argument that can be a tuple holding the two axes that hold the matrices.  So your calculation is simply

```
norms = np.linalg.norm(m, ord='fro', axis=(1, 2))
```

For example,

```
In [43]: import numpy as np

In [44]: rng = np.random.default_rng()

In [45]: m = rng.uniform(0, 3, size=(10, 8, 8))

In [46]: norms = np.linalg.norm(m, ord='fro', axis=(1, 2))

In [47]: norms
Out[47]: 
array([15.43326187, 12.18174753, 12.72366662, 14.20558871, 14.08558457,
       13.51040102, 13.38476228, 14.3334069 , 15.19745515, 14.46134742])
```

Answer (score 1):

```
list(map(lambda x: np.linalg.norm(x, ord='fro'), mats))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
foo = mats.reshape(100, -1)
np.sqrt(np.diagonal(foo @ foo.T))
```

(this is specifically for the Frobenius norm).

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with a list comprehension:

```py
norms = [np.linalg.norm(m, ord='fro') for m in mats]
```

Or with `numpy.vectorize`:

```py
@np.vectorize
def my_fun(m):
    return np.linalg.norm(m, ord='fro')

norms = my_fun(mats)
```